# pyparsing SkipTo and key = value input

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

I am trying to define a input parser using pyparsing. I have managed to get something like the following parsed correctly:

```
key = value
```

where value can be, for example an integer. This is the Python code:

```
import pyparsing as pp

_name = pp.Word(pp.alphas + '_', pp.alphanums + '_')
_key = _name + EQ
_value = pp.pyparsing_common.signed_integer

pp.dictOf(_key, _value)
```

Now I would like to add a "raw" data input:

```
$raw
H 0.0 0.0 0.0
F 1.0 1.0 1.0
$end
```

where anything between `$` and `$end` is "gobbled up" into a string, whose key will be `raw`. I have tried with:

```
import pyparsing as pp

SDATA = pp.Literal('$').suppress()
EDATA = pp.CaselessLiteral('$end').suppress()
data_t = pp.Combine(SDATA + pp.Word(pp.alphas + '_', pp.alphanums + '_')
                ) + pp.SkipTo(EDATA) + EDATA
data_t.setName('raw data')
data_t.setParseAction(lambda token: (token[0], token[1]))
```

and this works with the input string `'$raw\nH 0.0 0.0 0.0\nF 1.0 1.0 1.0\n$end'`
I can't however manage to combine the `key = value` parser with `data_t`. Anything obvious I am missing here? Or is it just not possible to combine the two?

**UPDATE**

This is the test input:

```
$raw
H 0.0 0.0 0.0
F 1.0 1.0 1.0
$end

int = 42
```

and this is the way I am combining the `key = value` and "raw" data parsers:

```
parser = pp.dictOf(_key, _value) ^ data_t
```

with parsing then invoked as:

```
tokens = parser.parseString(keywords).asDict()
```

This return an empty `dict`. Moving `int = 42` above `$raw ... $end` returns just `{'int': 42 }`.

Comment: Can you post how you are trying to combine those two expressions?

Comment: So your parser is looking for either a dict of key-values *OR* a data_t. I think you want one or more of either of these. Try: `parser = pp.OneOrMore(pp.dictOf(_key, _value) | data_t))` (use the '|' operator instead of '^', I think you will find it performs better, with no loss in parsing abilities).

Comment: With you last suggestion the parser gets stuck, unfortunately. I tried with `pp.OneOrMore((_key + _value) | data_t)` and this again returns an empty `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yowch! This is partially due to a bug in `dictOf`. To make progress on this, I defined the following:

```
kv_dict = pp.Dict(pp.OneOrMore(pp.Group(_key + _value)))
```

Then I defined my parser as:

```
parser = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Group(data_t) | pp.Group(kv_dict))
```

The grouping is important so that keys in one set don't step on those in another. (The bug in `dictOf` prevents including it like this inside a `OneOrMore`, since `dictOf` allows an empty dict, so it loops forever at the end of the string instead of terminating.)

Finally, I use `dump()` to see the results instead of `asDict()`. `asDict()` will only show parsed tokens that are named, which your `data_t` is not.

```
print(parser.parseString(sample).dump())
```

Gives:

```
[[('raw', 'H 0.0 0.0 0.0\nF 1.0 1.0 1.0\n')], [['int', 42]]]
[0]:
  [('raw', 'H 0.0 0.0 0.0\nF 1.0 1.0 1.0\n')]
[1]:
  [['int', 42]]
  - int: 42
```

If you want to add names in data_t, change the definition to this, and drop the parse action:

```
data_t = pp.Combine(SDATA + pp.Word(pp.alphas + '_', pp.alphanums + '_')
                )("name") + pp.SkipTo(EDATA)("body") + EDATA
```

Now I get:

```
[['raw', 'H 0.0 0.0 0.0\nF 1.0 1.0 1.0\n'], [['int', 42]]]
[0]:
  ['raw', 'H 0.0 0.0 0.0\nF 1.0 1.0 1.0\n']
  - body: 'H 0.0 0.0 0.0\nF 1.0 1.0 1.0\n'
  - name: 'raw'
[1]:
  [['int', 42]]
  - int: 42
```

Comment: Thanks! This works wonderfully! Too bad about `dictOf`: I was using it as I want to parse the text and dump the results as a "flat" dictionary to JSON. `dictOf` and `asDict` made it particularly easy without further post-processing of the results.